# AWS ACCESS KEY ISSUE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django

I accidentally pushed my access keys up to github and amazon contacted me with instructions on "fixing" the issue. I messed up and accidentally deleted the access key, thinking thats what i was supposed to do. Now all I get is 
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. 
I am using Django admin for posting items up to the s3 bucket i have set, but getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to invalidate that key anyway, because you don't know who had access to it.

Now you have to create a new access key on IAM and use it in your scripts.

Make sure the new created key is excluded from your git push.

Comment: thank you that worked! i also had to exit the virtual env and go back in it again for it to change completely because i changed it in pycharm and it wasn't registering I guess.

Comment: Happy that worked for you. Please mark the answer as correct.